# Plot the curve of a group of parametric equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions, plot-themes

This question is about how to use MMA to plot a curve from solution of a group of parametric equations. To take an algebraic equations as an example, like:

\begin{align}
x^2 - y^2 &= t^2 \\
xy &= t  \qquad ,
\end{align}
where the range of the parameter $t$: $t \leq - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $t \geq \frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}$.

I managed to solve the equations to get an explicit form via MMA:

```
 Solve[{-x^2 + y^2 == t^2, x y == t}, {x, y}]
```

but I don't know how to plot the graph $\{x,y\}$ under the range $t \leq - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $t \geq \frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}$.

---

Based on rhermans's code, I plotted two graphics for $t≤−1/\sqrt{2}$ and $t≥ 1/\sqrt{2}$, respectively,  and used `show` to combine the two results into one single graph.

[image]

The problem is solved.

Comment: That is actually referred to as an implicit form. If you look for "plot implicit function" (without the quotes) in the help browser, first hit is to `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[
  {x, y} /. Solve[{-x^2 + y^2 == t^2, x y == t}, {x, y}]
  ]
 , {t, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hey, @rhermans, Thank you! I put your code in MMA and just replace `{t, -(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}` with `{t, -8, -1/Sqrt[2]}` to plot one part of the range($ t \leq -1/\sqrt{2}$), or with `{t, 1/Sqrt[2],8}` to plot the other part ($t \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$). 

Is there any smarter way to plot the two parts in a single graph?

Comment: @ZoeRowa [Read this first](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397). You should ask a new question and **explain clearly** what you need now.